# Can I schedule only one specific GitLab CI/CD job?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

At the moment, I have a couple of CI/CD jobs configured in `gitlab-ci.yaml` within a pipeline. For instance, I have the build and deploy configured within one branch. One of the jobs is creating a backup.

I would like to schedule only the backup job every night. However, in the schedule section of GitLab CI/CD, I can only select a branch or a tag. This will result in all the stages/jobs to be triggered, whereas I only want the backup to be triggered.

I've seen the option to configure `rules` and `excepts` to only trigger the jobs in a certain context. That, however, feels a bit like a patch solution. Is there another way to trigger only a single job in the Gitlab CI/CD scheduler?

Answer (score 11):

> I've seen the option to configure rules and excepts to only trigger the jobs in a certain context. That, however, feels a bit like a patch solution. Is there another way to trigger only a single job in the Gitlab CI/CD scheduler?

No, there's no other way than using `rules:` or `only:`/`except:` to control which jobs run when the pipeline is triggered by a schedule.

You can make this more manageable by splitting your pipeline configuration to multiple files then using the appropriate `rules:` on the `include:`

```yaml
include:
  - local: /do-backup.yml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
  - local: /do-pipeline.yml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "schedule"'
```

That way you don't have to necessarily apply the same `rules:` to every single job and you can define additional `rules:` per job with less conflict.